# Get all IP-Addresses in C

Tags: c, winsock

I have the following problem. I have to write a Plugin for Pidgin in the Language C. I am completely new to C.
I found the following Code.

```
  WORD wVersionRequested;
  WSADATA wsaData;
  char name[255];
  char* ip;
  PHOSTENT hostinfo;
  wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD( 2, 0 );

  if ( WSAStartup( wVersionRequested, &wsaData ) == 0 )  {
        if( gethostname ( name, sizeof(name)) == 0) {
              if((hostinfo = gethostbyname(name)) != NULL) {
                    ip = inet_ntoa (*(struct in_addr *)*hostinfo->h_addr_list);
              }
        }
        WSACleanup( );
  }
```

I have the IP-Address 
172.28.52.220
But because of my VMWare I also have the IP 10.0.1.3.
In my Plugin now the IP 10.0.1.3 is assigned to my variable.
i need the IP to find out in which location of my company I am. I need hte 172...

Now I could find in the winsock2.h that *hostinfo->h_addr_list contains the list of Ip addresses. How can I assign the 172. Address to my IP_Variable?

Thank you in advance for your help!

---

Edit:
Just to clarify: I don´t want to have my external IP address. I need my internals.

Comment: I don´t want to have my external IP. That are all Internal IPs!

Comment: Since you can communicate with the host machine from VMWare ask it what it's IP is. Also, there is a **traceroute** program that does this, check it's source code.

Comment: @iharob: Traceroute is the wrong program to look at, it does everything in raw ICMP, and the benefit is that it gives you the IP addresses of all the intermediate nodes in your network.  Figuring out the IP addresses of your endpoints is far, far easier.

Comment: @DietrichEpp can you please post an answer then?

Comment: @iharob: I'm sorry, I just don't understand the question.  I don't know what IP address is desired, or why.

Comment: I have two Ethernet-Adapter. The first one is my IP 172.28.52.220 this the IP-Address I nee because i need it to verify my location. If I were at our other location in Cologne I would have an IP like: 172.28.40.* So I can know whether I am in Frankfurt or in Cologne. The Problem is I have for my webdevelopment a VMWare. Which has the IP 10.0.1.3 In my checkup whether I am in Cologne or in Frankfurt I only get the IP 10.0.1.3 which isn´t helpful because with that IP I can´t know at which Location I am.

Comment: This sounds like a VMWare configuration issue.  There are multiple ways to configure the guest/host networking, it sounds like you want guest and host to share an IP address.

Comment: Ok I see. Then I´ll have a look at that. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Did you try looping over all the values in `h_addr_list` and find one that starts with 172?

Comment: @PaulRooney that´s an answer I´ve waited for. I don´t have a clue how to do that.  I found this  ip = inet_ntoa (*(struct in_addr *)*hostinfo->h_addr_list); in the Internet. Do you have a small example on how I could loop over that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example I tested on on `linux`. I dont have access to a Windows system until tomorrow, but can test and update the answer if required.

It is comparable to the Windows version only without the `WSAStartup` call at the beginning.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main()
{
  char hostnamebuff[100];

  if(gethostname(hostnamebuff, 100) == 0)
  {
    struct hostent* hostinfo = gethostbyname(hostnamebuff);
    printf("host name is %s\n", hostnamebuff);

    if(hostinfo != NULL)
    {
      char** paddrlist = hostinfo->h_addr_list;

      printf("host list is\n");      
      while(*paddrlist != NULL)
      {
         char addrbuff[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
         if(inet_ntop(hostinfo->h_addrtype, *paddrlist, addrbuff, hostinfo->h_addrtype == AF_INET ? INET_ADDRSTRLEN : INET6_ADDRSTRLEN))
         {
           printf("%s\n", addrbuff);

           if(strncmp(addrbuff, "172.", 4) == 0)
           {
             printf("its a match\n");
             break;
           }
         } else
         {
           printf("failed to convert an address\n");
         }
         paddrlist++;
      }
    } else
    {
      printf("failed on gethostbyname\n");
    }
  } else
  {
    printf("failed on gethostname errno=%d\n", errno);
  }
}
```

The `h_addr_list` member of `hostent` is a NULL terminated array of pointers to char* (so its double pointer). My example shows how to traverse this. Hope it helps.

As for this distinctly smelly bit of code

```
ip = inet_ntoa (*(struct in_addr *)*hostinfo->h_addr_list);
```

This is a highly unreadable way of getting the first entry in the address list.

Comment: It’s been a long time. Not sure why I changed it but I think what you have done is right.